# Trying to round the values of a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, rounding

```
table_percentages = {'e': 42.857142857142854, 'g': 28.57142857142857, 'x': 14.285714285714285, 'c': 14.285714285714285}
```

Trying to round the values in the dictionary above to two decimal places. I attempted the following For Loop, but didn't get the desired output. I only received a single output, i.e. one  rounded value.

```
rounded_percentages = {}
for key in table_percentages:
    rounded_percentages = round(table_percentages[key], 2)
print(rounded_percentages)
```

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```py
rounded_percentages = {}
for key in table_percentages.keys():
    rounded_percentages[key] = round(table_percentages[key], 2)
print(rounded_percentages)
```